# Frobenius reciprocity law in the $p$-adic group represenation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-adic classical group and let $P_0$ be a minimal parabolic subgroup of $G$. Let $P=MN$ be a
standard parabolic subgroup containing $P_0$. Let $\text{Ind}$ and $ |_M$ be the normalized parabolic induction functor and Jacquet functor, respectively.

Then for smooth representations $\pi$ of $G$ and $\rho$ of $M$, the Frobenius reciprocity law says that
$$\text{Hom}_{G}(\pi, \text{Ind}(\rho))\simeq \text{Hom}_{M}(\pi|_M,\rho).$$

I am wondering whether
$$\text{Hom}_{G}(\text{Ind}(\rho),\pi)\simeq \text{Hom}_{M}(\rho, \pi|_M)$$ does hold.

In Theorem 2.29 of [http://people.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/Jerusalem_2010/GradStudentSeminar/B-Zel-RepsGL-Usp.pdf](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/Jerusalem_2010/GradStudentSeminar/B-Zel-RepsGL-Usp.pdf), it does hold for $\pi=\pi_1^{\vee}$, where $\pi_1$ is a smooth representation and $^\vee$ denotes its contragredient dual.

If it does not hold for general $\pi$, what condition of contragredient dual was used in this this Frobenius law of Bernstein and Zelevinski?

Comment: P. Cartier's article "Representations of p-adic reductive groups" in the Corvallis volumes (Proc Symp AMS 33) discusses the limitations on your second form of Frobenius Reciprocity. There still is an adjunction (which is important to know half-exactness of that induction functor), but the adjoint is not (in general) the obvious restriction.

Comment: @Paul, thank you for your comment! I took a look on Corvallis book! It seems that page 124 below -5 line discuss it. Is this the reason that Theorem 2.29 of the Bernstein and Zelevinski paper uses contragredient dual in their Frobenius reciprocity law instead of smooth representation?

Comment: @Paul, I found that there is second adjointness property by Bernstein. http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Unpublished_texts/unpublished_texts/Bernstein87-second-adj-from-chicago.pdf  However, it pertains to Jacquet functor with respect to opposite parabolic subgroup $\overline{P}$ not $P$. Is it different with Cartier’s article?

Comment: there are reasons to describe various things in terms of the opposite parabolic, but I would be very surprised if this were the key issue. Still, I have been surprised before! Rather, I think there are more hypotheses for the "other" adjunction. For example, exactly what hypotheses are imposed on "algebraic" repns? Years ago, when I looked at the Bernstein article, I did not quite understand... and still don't, since somehow the viewpoint of the Cartier article is more similar to mine. Surely there is an interpretation in which Bernstein's assertion is true. :)